# How can I install /usr/bin/free in ubuntu bionic

Tags: ubuntu

for some software for some reason, they depend on the command `/usr/bin/free`, can you guide me how to install in ubuntu bionic distribution

No clue which package includes this

Answer (score 1):

Just noticed, it exists in old distribution, so I use `dpkg -S /usr/bin/free` which points to `procps`

```
# dpkg -S /usr/bin/free
procps: /usr/bin/free
```

Comment: You can also search for files provided by packages online: https://packages.ubuntu.com/search?suite=bionic&keywords=%2Fusr%2Fbin%2Ffree&searchon=contents